# what is the difference between using () and {} when creating Reads. I had to explicitly call apply when using {}

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In the following code, if I use `()`, I don't need to explicitly call `apply` of `CanBuilder`

```
implicit val pReads:Reads[P] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").readNullable[UUID] and
    (JsPath \ "description").read[String] and
...
)(P.apply _)
```

But if I use `{}`, I have to call `apply`. Why?

```
implicit val pReads:Reads[P] = {
    (JsPath \ "id").readNullable[UUID] and
    (JsPath \ "description").read[String] and
...
}.apply((P.apply _))
```

Comment: No one can answer this, unless you specify what that `Read` and `JsPath` is. Are you using play-json ?

Comment: yes, sorry, was ambiguous

Comment: And what is the error message you get for if you don't call apply ?

Comment: This is just because of how the language syntax is defined. The `(...)` in the first case is parsed as a `SimpleExpr1` which is allowed to have a `ArgumentExprs` after it. But the `{...}` in second case is parsed as a `BlockExpr` which can not have those arguments after it. The addition of `.apply` allows it to be parsed as a `SimpleExpr1` by rule `SimpleExpr1 := SimpleExpr ‘.’ id` since `BlockExpr` is also a `SimpleExpr` by rule `SimpleExpr := BlockExpr`. Refer to language specification here - https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html

Comment: It will work all the same if you put another parenthesis around `{...}` and make it `({})(P.apply _)` by again matching `({...})` to the same rule as the first one - `SimpleExpr1 = ‘(’ [Exprs] ‘)’` and then matching `({})(P.apply _)` to `SimpleExpr1 := SimpleExpr1 ArgumentExprs`

Comment: well explained. Thanks. Happy to accept your answer. Also, wondering whether  marking down my question was necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Apologies, I doubted it was you